# Showing that a series of sets are cumulative by induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

The sets describing the terms of an expression grammar are defined as follows:

$$
S_0 = \emptyset
$$

$$
S_{i+1} = \{true, false, 0\} 
∪ \{succ(t1), pred(t1), iszero(t1) | t1 ∈ S_i\}
∪ \{if(t1) then\{t2\} else \{t3\} | t1, t2, t3 ∈ S_i\}
$$

We need to show that $S_{i} \subseteq S_{i+1}$

Since sets are defined based on the terms of the previous ones, induction should work, right?

The base case is trivial, $\emptyset \subseteq { true, false, 0 }$

Then, for the inductive case, I've seen solutions assume $S_k \subseteq S_{k+1}$ is true for some arbitrary $k$, and then either seamlessly 'prove' the same stands for $S_{i}$ and $S_{i+1}$, or try to prove that all $s \in S_i$ also $\in S_{i+1}$, but both of those lines of reasoning seem to me like they're skipping over some (perhaps trivial) steps.

Here's an excerpt of a proof for clarity:

> When $i = 0$, there is nothing to prove. Next, supposing that $i = j + 1$, for some $j ≥ 0$, and that $S_j ⊆ S_i$, we must show that $S_i ⊆ S_{i+1}$ - that is, for any term $t \in S_i$, we must show $t \in S_{i+1}$. So suppose we have $t \in S_i$. By the definition of $S_i$ as the union of three sets, we know that $t$ must have one of three forms:

> $t \in \{true, false, 0\}$. In this case, we obviously have $t \in S_{i+1}$, by the definition of $S_{i+1}$.

> $t \in \{ succ(t1), pred(t1), iszero(t1) \}$, where $t1 \in S_j$. Since $S_j ⊆ S_i$ by the induction hypothesis, we have $t1 \in S_i$, so $t \in S_{i+1}$ by definition of $S_{i+1}$.

> $t \in \{ if(t1)then\{t2\} else \{t3\} \}$, where $t1, t2, t3 \in S_j$. Again, since $S_j ⊆ S_i$ by the induction hypothesis, we have $t \in S_{i+1}$, by the definition of $S_{i+1}$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: We can't comment on problems with a proposed proof that we can't see. Please make your question more specific about the details.

Comment: Sure, I've added an example of a proof.

Comment: Thanks. Your proof looks fine to me.